# Apex class creating multiple opportunities for each contact

Tags: apex, batch

I am working on one apex class which needs to create or update opportunity for a Contact. if no opportunity exists then I am creating Opportunity else I will update opportunity.

but the issue here is if I insert two contacts then my code is creating two opportunities for each Contact where it should create only one.

Can anyone help me out in this issue here if possible please.

My code is below

```
List<Contact> allcontacts = [SELECT Id, Name,AccountId,SIS_Student_ID__c,FirstName,LastName from Contact];
    List<SIS_Staging__c> allstages = [select Id,Name,SIS_Application_Id__c,AdmTyp__c,Resident_Tuition__c,ActnRsn__c,Admit_Term__c,Email__c,Home_Country__c,Plan__c,Prog1__c,Prog__c,
                                      ProgActn__c from SIS_Staging__c];
    set<Id> contactId = new set<Id>();
    set<string> studentId = new set<string>();
    for(Contact contactall : allcontacts){
        contactId.add(contactall.Id);
        studentId.add(contactall.SIS_Student_ID__c);
    }
    List<Opportunity> oppUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Opportunity> oppInsert = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id,Opportunity> opptoContact = new Map<Id,Opportunity>();
    Map<string,SIS_Staging__c> sistoopp = new Map<string,SIS_Staging__c>();
    List<Opportunity> opp2 = [SELECT Id,Student__c,Name from Opportunity where Student__c IN: contactId];
    for(Opportunity oppObj: opp2){
        opptoContact.put(oppObj.Student__c,oppObj);
    }
    List<SIS_Staging__c> stages = [select Id,Name from SIS_Staging__c where Name IN: studentId];
    for(SIS_Staging__c sisobj: stages){
        sistoopp.put(sisobj.Name,sisobj);
    }
    for(Contact cont1: allcontacts){
        for(SIS_Staging__c sist1: allstages){
        if(opptoContact.containsKey(cont1.Id)){
            Opportunity opp = opptoContact.get(cont1.Id);
            opp.Name = cont1.FirstName +''+ cont1.LastName + '-' +  sist1.SIS_Application_Id__c;
            opp.AccountId = cont1.AccountId;
            opp.Student__c = cont1.Id;
            opp.CloseDate = system.today()+60;
            opp.StageName = 'New';
            opp.SIS_Application_Id__c = sist1.SIS_Application_Id__c;
            opp.Admit_Type__c = sist1.AdmTyp__c;
            opp.Resident_Tuition__c = sist1.Resident_Tuition__c;
            oppUpdate.add(opp);
        }
        else{
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
            opp.Name = cont1.FirstName + cont1.LastName + sist1.SIS_Application_Id__c;
            opp.AccountId = cont1.AccountId;
            opp.Student__c = cont1.Id;
            opp.CloseDate = system.today()+60;
            Opp.StageName = 'New';
            opp.SIS_Application_Id__c = sist1.SIS_Application_Id__c;
            opp.Admit_Type__c = sist1.AdmTyp__c;
            opp.Resident_Tuition__c = sist1.Resident_Tuition__c;
            oppInsert.add(opp);
        }
    }
    }
    if(!oppInsert.IsEmpty()){
        insert oppInsert;
    }
    if(!oppUpdate.IsEmpty()){
        update oppUpdate;
    }
```

Comment: Try to debug your code, the issue may occur in nested `for` loop because it is n*m

Comment: hello Sarvesh, yes the issue is happening in for loop where I am iterating the SIS_Staging__c object,actually from SIS_Staging__c object I am creating contact once Contact is created then I need to update few fields from SIS_Staging__c to opportunity field so I used for loop which is causing the issue here, can you please help me out on this issue